# Symfony2 multiple firewall loop error in one of them

Tags: symfony

I have a problem with my application. I set it up three firewalls for each section. One for the backend, one for frontend and one for an extranet section. All of them has the same user provider (FOSUserBundle) and it was working fine until I add a new firewall (extranet). Now, in this firewall, when I try to access to domain.com/extranet/ I get a infinite loop, but the other firewalls work fine.

Here is my config:

security.yml

```
firewalls:
extranet:
    pattern: /extranet(.*)
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        login_path:     extranet_login
        check_path:     extranet_login_check
        default_target_path: extranet_home
    logout:
        path:           extranet_login_logout
        target:         page_home
    anonymous:    false
    security:     true
    context:      application
    remember_me:
        key: XXXXXXX
        lifetime: 86400
admin:
    pattern: /admin(.*)
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        login_path:     admin_login
        check_path:     admin_login_check
        default_target_path: admin_home
    logout:
        path:           admin_logout
        target:         page_home
    anonymous:    true
    security:     true
    context:      application
    remember_me:
        key: XXXXXXX
        lifetime: 86400
main:
    pattern: ^/
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
    logout:       true
    anonymous:    true
    security:     true
    context: application
    remember_me:
        key: XXXXXXX
        lifetime: 86400
```

access_control:

```
- { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

- { path: ^/extranet/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/extranet/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/extranet/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

- { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

- { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
- { path: ^/extranet/, role: ROLE_DISTRIBUTOR }
```

routing.yml

```
    #Login
login_check:
    pattern: /login_check

logout:
    pattern: /logout

#extranet login
extranet_login:
    pattern:  /extranet/login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

extranet_login_check:
    pattern:  /extranet/login_check
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

extranet_logout:
    pattern:  /extranet/logout
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }

#admin login
admin_login:
    pattern:  /admin/login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

admin_login_check:
    pattern:  /admin/login_check
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

admin_logout:
    pattern:  /admin/logout
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }
```

And finally, my security controller.

```
class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function renderLogin(array $data)
    {
        $requestAttributes = $this->container->get('request')->attributes;

        if ('admin_login' === $requestAttributes->get('_route')) {
            $template = sprintf('WebBundle:Backend:login.html.twig');
        } elseif ('extranet_login' === $requestAttributes->get('_route')) {
            $template = sprintf('WebBundle:Extranet:login.html.twig');
        } else {
            $template = sprintf('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig');
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse($template, $data);
    }
}
```

What could be wrong? I try a lot of changes, but when I fix that, another fails...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why have you defined `anonymous: false` in extranet firewall block?

Comment: @DanMironis That it's... I did something wrong with the copy&paste! I'm testing now, but I think that it has solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said Dan Mironis, the problem was that I set anonymous: false in the extranet firewall. I changed it to true and now seems that it's working. Thank you!